# Mocha Rerun Tests X amount in script

Tags: javascript, node.js, testing, mocha.js

I have my mocha command to execute in Node configured in my package.json file

```
**"NightBuildRegretionExecution":** "mocha ./Test/**/test.js --timeout 100000 --parallel --reporter mochawesome --require mochawesome/register"
```

My script it's used in GITHUB actions to configure the job.

Now I want to tell in this script to run the test case 100 times for example.

Is there any property in Mocha framework that allow me to define this on the script?